# Create a variable from each item in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to step through a PHP array and create a variable for each entry in it. My array (**$array**) looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Arthur
            [last_name] => Dent
            [planet] => Earth
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Ford
            [last_name] => Prefect
            [planet] => Betelgeuse
        )

)
```

I have got the following:

```
$0_first_name = $array['0']['first_name'];
$0_last_name = $array['0']['last_name'];
```

But this is pretty time consuming, and means I need to explicitly declare each one and then can't allow for extra entries within the array at each level.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Can you explain for what is it?

Comment: Why do you need to have them as seperate variables? An array is basicly a collection of variables.

Comment: Why do people think its a good idea to create scalar variables from array contents. **Use the array its not toxic**, and its incredibly more flexible that scalar variables with silly names

Comment: PS: `$0_first_name` is not a valid variable name. Character 1 has to be an alpha

Comment: The **BEST** way of doing this, per your request, is to keep the array structure and use a `foreach(){}` loop unless you can prove why your situation is special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do what I think you are trying to do.

```
$data = array(
    array('first_name' => 'Arthur', 'last_name' => 'Dent', 'planet' => 'Earth'),
    array('first_name' => 'Ford', 'last_name' => 'Prefect', 'planet' => 'Betelgeuse')
);

foreach( $data as $i => $arr ){
    foreach( $arr as $key => $value ){
        ${$key . $i} = $value;
        ${$i . '_' . $key} = $value;
    }
}
echo $first_name0, $first_name1, ${'0_first_name'};
```

Obviously, I have the integer after the name, but it's trivial to reverse them and have something like `$0first_name` or `$0_first_name` - but they need to be handled differently when outputting them - `${'1_first_name'}`, etc. - again, as has been pointed out, - it is not the best approach for maintainability, so now I'll go off and rethink all the bad decisions I have made in life.

Comment: Haa `Arthur Dent & Ford Prefect`  +1

Comment: Yeah, I particularly like the subject matter involved in the array - a classic!

Comment: Opps, now you went to far. variable names starting with numerics, give it a try and see what happens [see previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854685/create-variable-from-each-item-in-php-array#comment65073863_38854685)

Comment: As pointed out by @RiggsFolly, a variable beginning with an integer will not work but there is a little trick to get around that if that is the desired format - use `${'0_first_name'}`

Comment: Ouch! And maintaining that code will be the best fun ever! Specially for the poor dope that gets a rush update and has never seen the code before

Comment: true - nothing in life is easy

Comment: It can be if developers would just KISS

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer and all the comments! I thought I needed to extract each one to then set as a variable to use in my CMS, but I have used a variation of the answer above to get where I needed to.